# Cloud run logs in GCP shows that web app is running successfully but the generated domain name is never reachable

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, networking, containers, google-cloud-run

I have followed and read the documentation instructions very carefully and have been able to deploy a Django app connected to a PostgreSQL database. The issue is that the deployment does result a success, and looking at the instance logs here is what is shown:

I also tried with Gunicorn and it seems to have the same result. And configured the networks to allow all and allow unauthenticated invocations. What can be the issue here?
[image]

Comment: I didn't catch your issue. Where is the issue?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere When vising https://django-run./ ... as they are instructing. That domain doesn't show anything. With DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN in the browser

Comment: What's this django-run domain? Where did you find it? Where did you see it?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere It showed up after running gclound run deploy. It is in the above picture too, shown in the cloud run service. Here is how it looks: h t t p s : / / django-cloudrun-qhwwdflsuq-lz.a.run.app

Comment: It works well on my side. I have a 404, but the server answered me. I don't understand the issue

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere my server didn't answer me at all, not even 404, it says "Hmmm… can't reach this page" in my microsoft edge, it says that the domain name doesn't exist with DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. But thank you this helped me a lot! Now, I know that the issue is not about deployment or some network configuration.

Comment: here what I have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2PHx.png

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere looks like some DNS issue, I switched from Edge to Opera and activated the option: Use DNS-over-HTTPS instead of the system’s DNS settings

Now it works, thanks!

Comment: Conclusion: Never ever use Microsoft product!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: in order to by-pass DNS configuration on browser, I changed my DNS settings on my IPv4 settings and used the following DNS servers:

[image]

Now, it works on Postman too in my local computer.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing this as a community wiki for the benefit of others

@guillaume blaquiere tested that the server is working well but returns a 404.This allows @Samir Ahmane to confirm that the issue doesn't have anything to do with the deployment or network configuration.

**Solution:** @Samir Ahmane solved the issue by switching from Microsoft Edge to Opera and activated the option DNS-over-HTTPS instead of the system’s DNS settings.